# VBA - How to get elements by src or alt at internet explorer

Tags: vba

I'm having a little trouble with my code.
Follow the code below

```
<a href="LINK HERE"><img src="IMAGE LINK HERE" border="0" alt="Page suivante" align="right"></a>
```

For reasons of confidentiality, I canno't show the link. I would like to know, how can I click on this link using "alt".

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? It would help if you paste the code you're having trouble with. Here are some general web scraping tips http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/

Comment: We should see your coding attempt as your problems may not only be related to selecting by attribute which can be done using css selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors  We have no idea if you are using xmlhttp or IE or selenium...... etc

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with CSS selectors (so am sure someone else can/will give you a better answer), but this seems to work for me if I add a reference for `Microsoft HTML Object Library`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SomeCssSelection()

    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = "<a href=""LINK HERE""><img src=""IMAGE LINK HERE"" border=""0"" alt=""Page suivante"" align=""right""></a>"

    Dim targetElement As MSHTML.HTMLImg
    Set targetElement = html.querySelector("img[alt=""Page suivante""]")

    Debug.Assert Not (targetElement Is Nothing)

End Sub
```

As pointed out by QHarr, single quotes can be used to make the code easier to read:

```
Set targetElement = html.querySelector("[alt='Page suivante']")
```

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for input, edited post to reflect comment.

Comment: I'll try to do that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do I click on this element? I'm having some troubles,

Comment: @GustavoSarturi I can't test right now, but once you've set `targetElement`, you should be able to do something like `targetElement.click`